# Laravel eloquent query with sum of values from another table on a condition

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have two tables. Transaction and allocation.
one Transaction can have multiple allocation.
Relationships defined as follows:

**Inside Allocation Table**

```
class Allocation extends Model
{
    public function transaction_fk(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Transaction','transaction_id');
    }
}
```

**Inside Transaction Table**

```
class Transaction extends Model
{
    public function allocations() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Allocation');
    }
}
```

I need to query all the rows from the transaction table with a certain ID along with the sum of allocations for that transaction line **with sum of allocation totals if transaction total is not equal to sum of allocation totals**. Something along the lines of the following:

```
Transaction::where('id',$id)->where('amount','!==','sum(allocations.amount)')->with('balance' as 'sum(allocations.amount)')->get();
```

This query does not work. What am I missing?

I was able to do it as a simple query which I looped through and made a second query and added to list. It gives me the correct result. As you can see this is long-winded and slower. I need to do it straight away while querying the database one time.

```
 $transactions2 = Transaction::where('contact_type','supplier')
    ->where('contact_id',$ehead->supplier_id)
    ->get();

    $transactions = [];
    foreach ($transactions2 as $item) {
       $sum = Allocation::where('transaction_id',$item['id'])->get()->sum('amount');
       if($item['amount'] !== $sum){
        $item->unallocated_amount = $sum;
        array_push($transactions, $item);
       }

    }
```

Comment: First thing that is noticeable is your condition is wrong. !== needs to be <> , but also you might need to use a Raw method - https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods

Comment: didn't my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use groupBy and aggregation functions if you want to do this in a single query.

```
$items = Transaction::query()
            ->join('allocations', 'transactions.id', '=', 'allocations.transaction_id')
            ->groupBy('transactions.id')
            ->having('transactions.amount', '<>', 'sum(allocations.amount)')
            ->whereIn('transactions.id', $transactions2)
            ->select('transactions.*')
            ->get();
```